# How to reuse the combination of UI elements?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In my UWP xaml file, I need to reuse the StackPanel like below in the below ScrollViewer code, how to do it?

```
               <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
```

...

```
       <ScrollViewer  
        Width="1920" 
        Height="1020" 
        HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

                ...

            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) and define the `StackPanel` there:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App1.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
        </Button>
        <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
        </Button>
        <Button Content="button1" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

You can then create several instances of your `UserControl` in your `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer  
        Width="1920" 
        Height="1020" 
        HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <local:MyUserControl1 />
        <local:MyUserControl1 />
        <local:MyUserControl1 />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! For the 3 buttons in UserControl, (and consider if the UserControl is repeated)  if I want to access them in C# code, how to set/get each x:Name separately?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Do you want to access them in the file where the `ScrollViewer`is defined? Then you could give the `<local:MyUserControl1 />` element an `x:Name` and access the buttons using `userControlName.buttonName` provided that you set the [x:FieldModifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-fieldmodifier-attribute) of the buttons to `public`. Of course you also need to set the `x:Name` attribute of the buttons in the `UserControl`.